# Is there a way to Change label size according to portion of the chart it takes up?

Tags: r, ggplot2

There might be a simple way to do this, but I am not sure what it is. I want to take the labels and change their sizes. I know how to change the size of all of them, but I am looking to have it so that the larger the percent label, then the larger the font is. [Plot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqVCR.png)

```
data<-data.frame(count=c(39,36,19,6), category=c("a","b","c","d"))
data$fraction = data$count / sum(data$count)
data = data[order(data$fraction), ]
data$ymax = cumsum(data$fraction)
data$ymin = c(0, head(data$ymax, n=-1))

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#Create Plot
fill <- c("blue3","cyan3","darkgrey","forestgreen")

p1 = ggplot(data, aes(fill=category, ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3.5)) 
+ geom_rect(colour="White") +
 coord_polar(theta="y") +
 scale_fill_manual(values=fill)+
 theme_bw()+
 geom_label(aes(label=paste(data$fraction*100,"%"),x=4,y=
 (ymin+ymax)/2),inherit.aes = F)+
 theme(panel.grid=element_blank())+
 theme(axis.ticks=element_blank()) +     
 xlim(c(0, 4)) +
 theme(axis.text=element_blank()) +
 labs(title="donut plot")


 print(p1)
```

Comment: Maybe you can replace `geom_label` with `geom_text`?

Comment: It's not a good idea to edit the question completely after it's been asked and answered. You should leave the question as it was (about removing the box around labels) and ask a new one for your new request (about changing the size of the labels).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to remove the border around the labels. All you need is a `label.size = NA` in your `geom_label()`.

Replace your `geom_label()` with:

```
geom_label(aes(label=paste(data$fraction*100,"%"),x=4,y=
                   (ymin+ymax)/2),inherit.aes = F, label.size = NA)
```

and it should work.

[image]

Also you can remove the white boxes around the labels by adding a `fill = NA` if you want.

Comment: For future users - this was an answer to the original question. The OP later edited to the question that is shown now.